# Find all polynomials $f$ such that $f(x+m)=f(x)+m$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, functional-equations

I apologize if this is a very basic question but as someone with very limited experience solving functional equations, I'm more interested in the methods employed to tackle these kinds of problems, since I have a more advanced problem I'm trying to solve. I've tried to guess and check but haven't gotten beyond obvious solutions like $x+b$ and can't prove they're the only form a solution can take. squaring both sides and trying to find a way to group the RHS into terms of $f(x)+m$, but can't figure out where to go from there or if this is even a useful approach. To clarify, $f$ must be a polynomial and $m$ is some nonzero constant.
$$(f(x)+m)^2=f(x)^2+2mf(x)+m^2=f(x)(f(x)+m)+m(f(x)+m)$$
Would appreciate some hints or problem-solving strategies: thanks!

Comment: Use Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: I think $m$ can be any non-zero number; the crucial requirement is that  $f(x+m)=f(x) + m$ *for all $x$*.

Comment: Yes, I meant that m can be any non-zero integer: I'll edit the post to clarify that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider $g(x)=f(x)-x$; then $g$ is also a polynomial, and $g(x+m)= f(x+m) - x - m = f(x)-x=g(x)$ for all $m$, so $g$ is a constant function (this is the only periodic polynomial): that is, $g(x)=c$, so $f(x)=x+c$. You ask for general problem solving strategies for functional equations: one is "guess the answer and consider (unknown function - your guess) or (unknown function /your guess) depending on the context".

Answer (score 2):

By a simple recurrence, you can show that $f(km) = f(0)+km$ for all integer $k$. Now a polynomial of degree $d$ grows like $Cx^d$. There is a $C$ and an $R$ such that for all $x > R$,
$$|f(x)| \geq C |x|^d$$
This shows that the degree is equal to 0 or 1. A degree zero polynomial is constant, so $f$ is of degree one as you thought.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered this kind of method but it seems really useful!